# How do I install monogame on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: installation, monodevelop, ubuntu-12.04, monogame

I was following http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFs319ECDEM, but the badgerports.org repository doesn't seem to have monogame anymore. Could someone give me a better repository, or tell me another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install and build Monogame (the C#/XNA clone).

Follow the instructions in this link:

- http://www.sharms.org/blog/2012/06/getting-started-with-monogame-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: I know it's late, but I forgot to mark this as correct when I first asked this question. It worked!